# Angular 9 - Cannot set property "...." of undefined

Tags: angular, enums

Recently, we upgraded to Angular 9. However, there is an issue we're facing during run time. We have disabled Ivy because it was blocking our build and now everything seems to build fine. However, during run time, we get the following error:

```
Cannot set property "/sites/34" of undefined
```

This leads to an enum in our code, which looks like this:

```
enum Sites {
  SITES_ENDPOINT = '/sites/34'
}
```

I'm really not sure what's the issue and how it should be fixed. Should I refactor all my enums in some way? Should I change them to objects? Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Update:

Right beneath the definiton of the enum, in the same file, I have the following code:

```
enum Sites {
  SITES_ENDPOINT = '/sites/34'
}

const object = this;

@Injectable()
export class SitesService implements Http {
  ... 
  constructor() {
    sitesInit()
  }

  get<T>(path: string, opt?): Observable<T> {
    for (const key in Sites) {
      ...
    }
  }
}

function sitesInit() {
  object[Sites.SITES_ENDPOINT] = '/sites/345';
}
```

Comment: did you try removing the last ","?

Comment: yes, same result.

Comment: do you get any other errors before this one?

Comment: @geronimo678 Unfortunately, only this.

Comment: did you try to remove your node_modules directory and npm install? Perhaps this is a caching issue. The cache is saved in node_modules

Comment: It's a runtime issue, probably meaning that somewhere in your code you have something like `object[Sites.SITES_ENDPOINT] = xxx` with `object` being undefined

Comment: @David That's exactly what I have! So the fix would be to properly define `object` I suppose? As in my codebase, `object` was defined as `const object = this;`

Comment: Can you show how/where it's used then? It's a bit hard to say why `this` would be null, probably a callback not using arrow function

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you are trying to do, but there are several errors in your code. `this` will not refer to anything , the `sitesInit` function should be defined as a method. What do you expect `object` to point to ?

Comment: @birdybird03 why do you use the "function" keyword in Typescript? Why is the object out of the service and not inside? For me, the code does not make any sense...

Comment: @David So when compiling with ivy enabled, the object points to an object that has all the methods, enum properties and methods inside of the `SitesService` class. This means the `sitesInit` works fine and maps the default values and they are accessible in the object. The issue is, how to make it work with ivy disabled...

Comment: What's the point of doing this? Why not using proper `this` and class methods?

Comment: I don't understand, why you are setting object['/sites/34'] = '/sites/345'; in sitesInit. I think you misunderstand enums...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should move object and sitesInit() to your service. Because object and sitesInit are not exported they don't need to be static.

```
enum Sites {
  SITES_ENDPOINT = '/sites/34'
}

@Injectable()
export class SitesService implements Http {

  private object = {};

  ... 
  constructor() {
    this.sitesInit()
  }

  get<T>(path: string, opt?): Observable<T> {
    for (const key in Sites) {
      ...
    }
  }

  sitesInit() {
    this.object[Sites.SITES_ENDPOINT] = '/sites/345';
  }
}
```